# ¿Error en mostrar dato mediante switch case?

Tags: php

Si existen datos devueltos o recibidos por método $_POST tendrá el valor `process` si no existen valores devueltos o recibidos tendrá el valor `cancel`

El código lo plantee de la siguiente forma, pero existe un fatal error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\PayPal\exito.php on line 48

La linea 48 del error se refiere a la siguiente linea de código `else $this->action = 'cancel';`

**¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error, o cómo crear en `$_POST` un `true` & `false` para llegar a cabo el funcionamiento del siguiente código:?**

```
if(!empty($_POST)) $this->action = 'process';
else $this->action = 'cancel';
switch($this->action){
    case 'process':
        # code...
      echo "process";
        break;
    case 'cancel':
        # code...
      echo "cancel";
        break;
}
```

Comment: Podrías añadir el código completo de ese archivo por favor? Lo digo más que nada porque ahí te está diciendo que no estás en un contexto de objeto, "$this->" se utiliza para hacer referencia a propiedades de una clase. Saludos!!

Comment: Aparte del anterior comentario, tampoco le veo sentido a abrir un bloque `switch` en este caso. Si es `process` puedes ejecutar lo que tengas que ejecutar en la primera parte del `if` y lo demás lo ejecutas en el `else` , según veo el código ni siquiera sería necesario igualarlo a `cancel` a no ser que luego vayas a necesitar el valor de `$this->action`

Comment: @HectorJOrihuelaRuiz ese es todo el código, vaya no sabía que era dependiente de una clase ese ejemplo lo encontré en la web.

Comment: @A.Cedano Estaba usando por medio de método `$_GET` ejemplo `?action=process` & `?action=cancel` funciona bien me muestra los valores que corresponde en el `switch case` el problema es que si utilizó este método al modificar la URls mostrará otro dato y esto no debe ser, entonces pensé hacer lo mismo con método $_POST pero tengo ese problema del error no funcionó igual que método $_GET y podías darme un ejemplo en ambos el que me indicas y una posible solución a mi problema :) te lo agradecería

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### A.

Si quieres evaluar que el POST en general no esté vacío. Esta es una forma de hacerlo:

```
if ( !count($_POST)==0 )   //o !isset( $_GET )
{

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
    {
        echo $key." - ".$value;

        /*Si quieres usar un switch... case con el valor que hay en st*/
        if ($key=="st") 
        {
            switch($value)
            {
                case 'Pending':
                    # code para pending...
                    break;

                case 'Completed':
                    # code para completed...
                    break;

                default:
                    # otra cosa si hicera falta cuando no se cumplan las anteriores
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}else{

    echo "No hay datos en el POST";
}
```

---

### B.

Si tú recibes algo como esto en la URL:

```
?action=process
```

o como esto:

```
?action=cancel
```

Entonces puedes recuperar el valor de `action` de esta forma:

```
if (isset($_POST["action"])) 
{
    $action=$_POST["action"];
    switch($action)
    {
        case 'process':
            # code...
            echo "process";
            break;

        case 'cancel':
            # code...
            echo "cancel";
            break;

        default:
            # otra cosa si hicera falta cuando no se cumpla ni process ni cancel
            break;
    }
}else{

    echo "No hay ningún valor con la clave action en el POST";

}
```

---

### C.

Si tú quieres evaluar cualquier dato dentro del POST y, según tu comentario quieres un valor booleano. Puedes proceder de esta forma.

```
$bolPending=false;

if (isset($_POST["st"])) {
    if ($_POST["st"]=="Pending")
    {
        $bolPending=true;
    }
}
```

La variable `$bolPending` sólo será `true` cuando dentro del POST haya una clave llamada `st` y el valor de la misma sea `Pending`.

Comment: No ese es el problema por eso trataba de darle un nombre al `$_POST` cuando era verdadero `true` es decir si existen datos recibidos o devueltos, o si es falso `false` es decir cuando no existen ningún dato devuelto o recibido, los únicos datos que recibo por medio de `$_POST` es lo siguiente `tx='2MA54118PG701512T', st='Pending', amt='29.00', cc='EUR'` y esto datos los verifico que son recibidos por medio de: `foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {}`

Comment: @Josues yo había interpretado leyendo un comentario tuyo que recibías algo como `action` en la URL, de ahí mi respuesta. He editado indicando en **A** una forma de proceder para evaluar si el POST está vacío o no y actuar en consecuencia.

Comment: es perfecto los ejemplos son de mucha utilidad podría haber una **C** :) es decir tomar el valor `Pending`  del `array` del dato  `st='Pending'` si existe este valor `Pending` el `$_POST` será `true` y si no existe ese valor se entenderá que el  `$_POST` es `false` esto es lo último y no molesto más :) +1

Comment: **C** agregada @Josues.

Comment: Eres lo máximo dos pregunta se puede añadir más de un valor o solo se puede añadir un dato `if ($_POST["st"]=="Pending")`... y en este caso este valor del `$_POST` ya se podría utilizar en `switch(aqui que valor va la variable $bolPending){ case'Pendient':}` ya en este caso creo que sería una **D** Disculpa por tanta curiosidad :(

Comment: No he entendido bien @Josues. La variable `$bolPending` en el código que he puesto sólo tendrá dos valores posibles: `true` o `false`.  Si tú quieres actuar directamente sobre el valor `Pending` tendrías que recuperarlo, por ejemplo `$strPending=$_POST['st'];` No sé exactamente lo que quieres con el `switch ... case`, sólo ten en cuenta que `switch`  se usa generalmente **para evaluar una misma variable, la cual puede tener valores distintos**... usarlo para evaluar cada valor que hay en el POST no me parece buena idea, ya que en el POST hay valores independientes. No sé si me explico.

Comment: El `switch` aplicaría por ejemplo si en el apartado **A.**  tú esperas valores distintos dentro de cualquiera de las claves del POST. Por ejemplo, si tú tuvieras posibilidad de que **`st` tenga la palabra `Pending` u otra palabra**, entonces sí... en el apartado **A**, dentro del `if`  que lee las variables del POST puedes recuperar el valor de `st`  y aplicar un bloque `switch ... case`  sobre ese valor: `case: 'Pending'   #código para Pending  break; case: 'Completed'   #código para completed break; ...` y lo mismo puedes hacer con cualquier variable del POST.

Comment: entiendo es verdad que la variable `$bolPending` solo da como respuesta `true` & `false` se me paso por alto, lo que si se es que este valor siempre recibiré `st='Pending'` gracias :)

Comment: He tomado el ejemplo **A** pero quitantole el `if ( isset( $_POST ) && 0 === count($_POST) ) {]` dejándolo de la siguiente manera [https://ideone.com/mDK2dA](https://ideone.com/mDK2dA) es necesario crear una nueva pregunta o me puedes ayudar modificandolo  :) el problema es que cunado no existen datos no muestra el mensaje por defaul que tiene el `switch` cuando existe valores ese si funciona y muestra el mensaje de `Pending` lo que corresponda en ese campo el problema es cuando no existen valores no muestra el mensaje predeterminado que tiene :(

Comment: @Josues he modificado el apartado **A.**, creo que ahora queda más claro. Además no había probado el código y no funcionaba del todo bien. Lo que hay dentro de `if ( !count($_POST)==0 )` ,  incluido el `switch`, **sólo se ejecutará si hay algo dentro del POST o del GET...** si no hay nada, pasará aquí: `echo "No hay datos en el POST";` (penúltima línea). Cualquier cosa la puedes poner ahí. Esa condición está hecha precisamente para saber cuando el POST está vacío o no. Lo mismo ocurre con el if de la `$key`, si no existe `st` no entrará en el bloque `switch`

Comment: @Josues No, no está de más... el `switch` que yo puse sólo evalúa el valor de la clave `st`. Observa: `if ($key=="st") ...` mientras que el `else` que hay fuera del POST es para cuando el POST esté totalmente vacío. Creo que es mejor que plantees una nueva pregunta con la nueva situación, en la que expliques con más exactitud lo que quieres lograr. Así tendrás posibilidad de varias respuestas, aquí en comentarios no hay esa posibilidad y es más difícil entender el contexto.